# how to load image in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I'm running java web app hosted on tomcat, where I'm trying to load image, but shows nothing as like below
[image]

On the console I'm getting the following error message

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
```

I'm using the following code

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/LOGO.PNG"/>
```

Note: Previously it was working fine, when I'm trying it with new image I'm getting this.

How to resolve this?
Thanks in advence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/LOGO.PNG"/>
```

This will set the favicon icon for your webpage.

To show the image on your JSP page use img tag. Please check the image path from the JSP page.

```
<img src="images/LOGO.PNG">
```